# How to create a for loop in java for an ArrayList with different array types?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am new to java, and programming for that matter and I am looking to program an RPG game. Currently, I am trying to create an innovatory / item system. I think I have a good plan to keep track of items with multiple values by using arrays and ArrayLists. This has created a problem for me, however. I'm not sure how I would program a for loop to iterate over the contained arrays as they are different types. These are the relevant classes I have created, I have an abstract Unit class that has an ArrayList Item as part of its constructor, a Ranger class that extends Unit, an Item class, and a Game class that brings everything together. Here is the code that I am trying to create a for loop for:

```
// ex 1-1

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Game {

// here are the arrays that comprise a weapon item

static String[] weaponS = new String[] { "Weapon Name", "damage" };
static int[] weaponI = new int[] { 10 };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Item creation 

    Item weapon = new Item(weaponS, weaponI);

    // here is the ArrayList the weapon will go into

    ArrayList<Item> rangerInv = new ArrayList<>();

    // here is the ranger object which takes the ArrayList as a parameter 

    Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 10, 4, rangerInv);
    rangerInv.add(weapon);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is program a for loop that could return any value contained within the rangerInv ArrayList. It is important that I have these arrays contained within arrays like this because down the road I will be referencing the array locations to make modular code. For example I need to always be able to count on the items name being at weaponS 0 and damage being at weponI 0 and so on. Basically I would use these constant locations to make subsequent methods and game functionalities. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could write a for loop for an ArrayList containing different types of arrays?

Comment: You have to define two methods in Item Class. One for String array weaponS  and another for int array weaponI and then use the Iterator to iterate over arraylist get the Item object from arraylist and then call the respective method for printing.
Hope you understood

Comment: If you're creating a real game, and not just writing an exercise I suggest you read this wonderful (and not too long) series of blog posts: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

It specifically talks about creating types for a game with different types of characters and weapons. It's about C#, but it's very similar to Java.

Comment: You're showing an `ArrayList<Item> rangerInv`, so the simplest solution is `for (Item it: rangerInv) { /* do something with it */ }`. However, the article linked by Matt is 100% worth reading before you continue with your own implementation: learning what people who've tried this before you is super important to get into the habit of early.